# Creating a new column in a table using proc sql, need to multiply four other columns together

Tags: sql, sas

I'm creating a new table to count total billing by state. Total billing includes price, quantity sold, a discount per customer, and sales tax in each state. I need a new table that gives me the 50 states and the total billing in each state.

I've tried simply multiplying the 4 fields together, but that hasn't seemed to work.

```
proc sql;
create table jarod.total bill as
select
    State_CD,
    Sale_ID,
    PriceOUT*(1-Discount)*(1+State Sales Tax)
from jarod.sales
    order by State_CD;
quit;
```

I wanted to get the total sale price for each transaction, which i would then somehow sum by state (unsure how to do this either) but my table won't create due to error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an aggregation query:

```
proc sql;
create table jarod.total_bill as
    select State_CD, sum(PriceOUT*(1-Discount)*(1+State Sales Tax)) as total_billing
    from jarod.sales
    group by State_CD;
quit;
```

Comment: gordon, this seems to work for getting the total billing, but I want the total billing by state. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jarod . . . "total billing by state" presumably means by `state_cd`.  That is what this query calculates.

Comment: That's what I assumed as well... when i entered the code you suggested each state had the same exact total which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Jarod . . . You are only selecting `state_cde` and the `sum()`?  `proc sql` does some interesting things if other columns are present.

Comment: Make sure you included that right variable in the GROUP BY clause.  If you forget the GROUP BY then SAS will calculate the sum over all of the observations and remerge on to each record.  You will see a note about remerging of statistics if you don't do the group by correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the [proc freq](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_freq_sect025.htm) will help you, give it a try ^^